# Do you have to disconnect or somehow close http connection when using HTTPService

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Do I have to disconnect or somehow close http connection when using HTTPService in Flex. For one I notice that on the status bar of the browser (Firefox) I see (when I envoke HTTPService) Transfering data from (server name here), even after I get all the results back from the HTTPService.

One other quick question regarding HTTPService is, what is the maximum amount of data I can send in parameters when doing HTTPService. (either using GET or POST).

Thanx a bunch
Ladislav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You don't have to disconnect.  That is actually a Firefox bug.

The limits of HTTPService should be the same as those with regular HTTP requests in the browser.  I'm not sure what they are but certainly GET is very limited while POST is nearly limitless.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that GET has limits to sending large chunks of data, while with POST I never had any problems.